# how to split entries in a list by more than one delimiter Python

Tags: python, list, delimiter

I have a .txt file with entries separated by a newline and a comma, alternating.

```
x = file_1.read().split("\n")
...
x = ['10,0902', '13897,00641']
```

how can I also delimit by a comma? `.split("\n" and ",")`
does not seem to work

Answer (score 0):

`.split("\n" and ",")` is the same as `.split(True)` which doesn't make much sense.

You'd want to use [re.split](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split) so you can split by a regex:

```
import re

string = '1,2\n3,4'

print(re.split(r'(?:\n|,)', string))
#  ['1', '2', '3', '4']
```